# Error al intentar borrar un elemento objeto de ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy intentando hacer un programa creando un ArrayList como si se tratara de una base de datos para guardar un nombre y un stock de cada producto.

Al añadir un producto todo va bien pero al intentar borrar uno es cuando me da el error.

El programa tiene un menú para consultar, crear, borrar artículos y recoge los datos por scanner.
Les dejo el código que tengo y lo que he intentado hacer para borrar el elemento.

El error que me marca es java.util.ConcurrentModificationException.
Si alguien pudiera ayudar lo agradecería mucho y espero haberme explicado bien.

La clase principal no lo pongo aquí por que lo único que tiene es la inicialización de Tienda y un while para que siempre me pida una opción.

> Tienda

```java
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tienda {

    ArrayList<Productos> productos = new ArrayList<Productos>();
    Iterator<Productos> it= productos.iterator();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void menu() {
        System.out.println("1. Consultar\n2. Crear\n3. Borrar\n4. Salir");

        int opcion = sc.nextInt();

        switch(opcion) {

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Lista de productos: ");
                    for(int i=0;i<productos.size();i++) {
                        System.out.println("Producto: "+productos.get(i).getNombre()+" --- Stock: "+productos.get(i).getStock());
                    }
                break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Indique el nombre del producto para añadir: ");
                    String nombre = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Indique el stock del producto para añadir: ");
                    int stock = sc.nextInt();
                    productos.add(new Productos(nombre,stock));
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Indique el nombre del producto a borrar: ");
                    String n = sc.next();

                    while(it.hasNext()) {
                        Productos p = it.next();
                        if(p.equals(n)) {
                            it.remove();
                        }
                    }           
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.exit(0);

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Introduce una opcion correcta.");

                }
        }
}
```

> Productos

```java
package main;

public class Productos {

    String nombre;
    int stock;

    public Productos(String nombre, int stock) {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.stock=stock;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }
    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes al crear un iterador sobre un *ArrayList* vació ya que más tarde tratas de operar sobre tu lista usando ese mismo iterador.

Simplificando el problema:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Tienda theShop = new Tienda();

        theShop.test();
    }
}

class Tienda
{
    ArrayList<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    Iterator<Producto> productsIterator = productos.iterator(); // Esto producira el BUG más adelante...

    public void test()
    {
        this.mockProducts();
        this.showExistingProducts();
    }

    private void showExistingProducts()
    {
        int productsQuantity = this.productos.size();
        System.out.println("Existen " + productsQuantity + " productos: ");

        while(productsIterator.hasNext()) {
            Producto p = productsIterator.next();
            System.out.println(" - " + p.getNombre());
        }
    }

    private void mockProducts()
    {
        System.out.println("Añadiendo productos...");
        this.productos.add(new Producto("Foo", 1));
        this.productos.add(new Producto("Baz", 5));
        this.productos.add(new Producto("Qx", 2));
    }
}

class Producto
{
    private String nombre;
    private int stock;

    public Producto(String nombre, int stock) {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.stock=stock;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }
    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
}
```

Y la salida del programa será:

> Añadiendo productos... 
> Existen 3 productos:
>   Exception in thread
>   "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException  at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1042)
>     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:996)   at
>   Tienda.showExistingProducts(App.java:38)  at Tienda.test(App.java:23)
>     at App.main(App.java:10)

Hasta aquí solo **he reproducido tu problema**. Ahora el código funcionando:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Tienda theShop = new Tienda();

        theShop.test();
    }
}

class Tienda
{
    ArrayList<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    Iterator<Producto> productsIterator = null;

    public void test()
    {
        this.mockProducts();
        this.showExistingProducts();
    }

    private void showExistingProducts()
    {
        int productsQuantity = this.productos.size();
        System.out.println("Existen " + productsQuantity + " productos: ");

        // Aquí creo el iterador sobre la lista actualizada de productos:
        productsIterator = this.productos.iterator();

        while(productsIterator.hasNext()) {
            Producto p = productsIterator.next();
            System.out.println(" - " + p.getNombre());
        }
    }

    private void mockProducts()
    {
        System.out.println("Añadiendo productos...");
        this.productos.add(new Producto("Foo", 1));
        this.productos.add(new Producto("Baz", 5));
        this.productos.add(new Producto("Qx", 2));
    }
}

class Producto
{
    private String nombre;
    private int stock;

    public Producto(String nombre, int stock) {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.stock=stock;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }
    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
}
```

Ahora la salida del programa será:

> Añadiendo productos...
>  Existen 3 productos: 
>    - Foo
>    - Baz
>    - Qx

**Tendrías que actualizar el *iterador* cada vez que tratas de operar sobre la lista de productos** (ya que el número de productos puede haber cambiado). Aquí te dejo una versión más completa del programa (ver y eliminar productos), aparte tienes un pequeño fallo a la hora de eliminar un producto de la lista que he corregido (anotación FIXED):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Tienda theShop = new Tienda();

        theShop.test();
    }
}

class Tienda
{
    ArrayList<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    Iterator<Producto> productsIterator = null;

    public void test()
    {
        this.mockProducts();
        this.showExistingProducts();

        this.deleteProductByName("Foo");
        this.showExistingProducts();
    }

    private void showExistingProducts()
    {
        int productsQuantity = this.productos.size();
        System.out.println("Existen " + productsQuantity + " productos: ");

        // Aquí creo el iterador sobre la lista actualizada de productos:
        productsIterator = this.productos.iterator();
        while(productsIterator.hasNext()) {
            Producto p = productsIterator.next();
            System.out.println(" - " + p.getNombre());
        }
    }

    private void deleteProductByName(String productName)
    {
        System.out.println("Eliminando producto '" + productName + "'...");

        // Aquí creo el iterador sobre la lista actualizada de productos:
        productsIterator = this.productos.iterator();
        if (this.productos.size() > 0) {
            while(productsIterator.hasNext()) {
                Producto p = productsIterator.next();
                if(p.getNombre().equals(productName)) { // FIXED:
                    productsIterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void mockProducts()
    {
        System.out.println("Añadiendo productos...");
        this.productos.add(new Producto("Foo", 1));
        this.productos.add(new Producto("Baz", 5));
        this.productos.add(new Producto("Qx", 2));
    }
}

class Producto
{
    private String nombre;
    private int stock;

    public Producto(String nombre, int stock) {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.stock=stock;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }
    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
}
```

Y la salida:

> Añadiendo productos...
>  Existen 3 productos: 
>    - Foo
>    - Baz
>    - Qx
>  Eliminando producto 'Foo'...
>  Existen 2 productos: 
>    - Baz
>    - Qx

Comment: Muchas gracias Orici, el fallo era que inicializaba el iterador al principio y no cada vez que se actualiza el arraylist, no lo comprendía hasta ahora. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que inicializar el `Iterator` justo antes de hacer la consulta, de lo contrario sale ese error. Entonces puedes declararlo arriba asi:

```
Iterator<Productos> it;
```

Tambien recuerda que tienes que comparar `p.getNombre()`, no `p`.

Quedaria asi:

```
it = productos.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Productos p = it.next();
    if (p.getNombre().equals(n)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias DaniDekk, el fallo era ese, que inicializaba el iterador al principio y no cada vez que actualizaba el arraylist, un saludo.